# Custom taxonomy archive doesnt work

Tags: wordpress

here is my registerin taxonomy function to my posts.

```
add_action( 'init', 'marka_taxonomies', 0 );
function marka_taxonomies() 
{

  $labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Markalar', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Marka', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Markalarda Ara' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'Tüm Markalar' ),
    'parent_item'         => __( 'Alt Marka Kategorisi' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Üst Marka Kategorisi:' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Markayı Düzenle' ), 
    'update_item'         => __( 'Markayı Güncelle' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Yeni Marka Ekle' ),
    'new_item_name'       => __( 'Yeni Marka Adı' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Marka' )
  );  

  $args = array(
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_admin_column'   => true,
    'query_var'           => true,
    'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'marka' )
  );

  register_taxonomy( 'marka', array( 'post' ), $args );


}
```

Thnik everthing is normal but the taxonomy-marka.php doesnt work. I still get 404 Not found on title. And there is nothing on my taxonomy archive page. What should i do also where i am wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

When I updated my permalinks option the `taxonomy-marka.php` page listed my posts.